# Best practice for writing PDO Query?

Tags: 7

I have noticed one thing in all core files: all DB related operations are not in try-catch block.

So please suggest me whether it's good practice to put SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT query in try catch block.

Answer (score 2):

It's good practice to put *any* code that could potentially throw an exception in a `try...catch` (not just in Drupal-related code, and not just in PHP).

So yes, it's good practice to put your database queries in a `try...catch`.